# DateTimePicker not showing the Text value

Tags: vb.net, windows-10, datetimepicker

I have an windows forms application that uses a DateTimePicker.  It has worked for years.  Suddenly I find that it will not display the date in the textbox.  Checked is set to true.  Enabled is set to true. Visible is set to true.  I never changed any of these.  Format is set to Short which is really the only customization from default.  I stepped though and the Text Property shows the formatted short date.  When you look at the control, it just shows // with no information.  The thing is that it works when running on the Terminal Server "2008 R2".  My box is Windows 10.  I am worried that the latest Windows 10 update that did away with the Control Panel might have caused this.  Anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jaxi and @dbasnett thanks for you guidance.  I am using a Sub Main to start my program so I could not just check the box to enable visual styles.  What I found was that the call that @dbasnett suggested could be made in my sub main before I opened my form and it fixed the problem.

```
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()

    frmRun = New frmMain
    Application.Run(frmRun)
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles()
```

to the form load event.

Comment: Thanks, but this had no effect.

Comment: I had to add the line in my Sub Main before the form was opened.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

So apparently this is a problem due to a windows 10 update, in your project settings, try selecting "Enable XP Visual Styles". This information is taken from a comment in the thread linked above.